# thymeleafのラジオボタンの初期選択について

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

thymeleafで下記のような記述をしていますが、初期値が選択されません。

```
<input type="radio" th:value="${item.id}" th:field="*{selectId}" checked/>
```

th:fieldを利用していることが問題（th:fieldを外すと初期選択される）のようですが、th:fieldを外すとformに値が入らずにサーバー側へラジオボタンの値を渡すことができません。

この場合どのような記述にすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: checkedを外せば良いのでは

Answer (score 1):

```
th:checked="${item.key == '******'}"
```

とすると初期値は `******` で指定したものが選択されます。